# How to find exactly one pair of positive prime numbers, $p$ and $q$ such that $p-q=9$?

Tags: prime-numbers, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Show that there is exactly one pair of positive prime numbers, $p $and$ q $such that $p-q=9$

Then we have:
$p=q+9$

However if $p-q= \text{odd}$ then one of the prime numbers must be odd. Given the assumption if it has to be even, then 2 is the only even prime. Then $p=11$ and $q=2 $:

$11-2=9$

Did I miss anything ?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid proof.

Comment: "then one of the prime numbers must be odd" -> "then exactly one of the prime numbers must be odd".  "then one of the prime numbers must be odd" does not reject that both are odd.

Comment: I think you mean *only* one of the numbers is odd, I.e. one of the numbers is even and therefore $2$

Comment: Yes when the assumption said to show that there are exactly one pair of positive prime numbers I thought it meant the pair must be even . But now I’m thinking that is not necessarily the case , as long as the numbers are not negative

Comment: You should also remark that $p=2$ does not lead to a solution.

Comment: A bit better is to only consider $q$ which canot be odd since then $q+9$ is an even number greater than $2$. Hence the only remaining case is $q=2$ giving a solution.